# Prove (or disprove) this $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{n}$ is convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_{n}>0$ be a sequence, and $0<a\le 1$, such that
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n})^a$ converges.

> Prove or disprove
>   $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{n}$ is convergent.

I know that this is an old problem, but I think that we can find out more interesting solutions.

Comment: Wasn't this already asked, recently, on the site (and closed for lack of personal input)?

Comment: Can't you just let $a=1$?

Comment: @Did as Najib said, this is not the place to discuss this. So I am clearing the comments.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: as you said, this is not the place to discuss this. So I am clearing the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n})^a$ is convergence, so there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, that:

$$\forall n \geq n_0 \; (a_n)^{a}<1$$

So:

$$\exists n_0\in \mathbb{N}\  \forall n \geq n_0 \; a_n<1$$

You know that if $1>a_n>0$ you have $\frac{|a_n|}{n} \leq |a_n| \leq |(a_n)^a|$, so:

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}\right| \leq \left|\sum_{n=1}^{n_0} \frac{a_n}{n}\right|+\left|\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}\right| $$

Now $a_n>0$, so:
$$\left|\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n} \right|=\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty} \frac{|a_n|}{n} \leq \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(|a_n|)^{a}=\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(a_n)^{a}$$

Finally $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}\right| \leq \sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(a_n)^{a}+\left|\sum_{n=1}^{n_0} \frac{a_n}{n}\right|$$

$\displaystyle \left|\sum_{n=1}^{n_0} \frac{a_n}{n}\right|$ is finite sum, $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(a_n)^{a}$ is finite because $\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(a_n)^{a} < \infty$, so $\displaystyle \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n}\right| < \infty$.